# Golang pattern to kill multiple goroutines at once

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have two goroutines as shown in the snippet below. I want to synchronize them such that when one returns, the other one should also exit. What is best way in go to achieve this?

```golang
func main() {

  go func() {
    ...
    if err != nil {
      return
    }
  }()

  go func() {
    ...
    if err != nil {
      return
    }
  }()


}
```

I have simulated this scenario here https://play.golang.org/p/IqawStXt7rt and tried to solve it with a channel to signal a routine is done. This looks like there can be a write to closed channel resulting in a panic. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: use two channels, use close to signal completion https://play.golang.org/p/FQauwB7KFpS

Comment: The "cross defer close pattern!?" makes a lot of sense. I think I incorrectly assumed this can be solved with just one channel.

Comment: @CeriseLimón wont the ordering of the done's matter here? What if done2 returns first?
Changing the channels to be buffered with a size of 1 might be a fix.

Comment: The order of completion does not matter.  The main function waits for both goroutines to complete before printing a message and returning.

Answer (score 24):

You can use context for communication between two go routines.
For example,

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(3)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            // msg from other goroutine finish
            case <-ctx.Done():
                // end
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            // msg from other goroutine finish
            case <-ctx.Done():
                // end
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        // your operation
        // call cancel when this goroutine ends
        cancel()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I need to read up more on contexts. Will multiple calls to cancel cause a panic?

Comment: No, it will not. If you find it helpful, you can vote for this answer. thx~

Comment: Your answer has been very helpful and I upvoted it. However using contexts in such situations seem like an anti pattern https://dave.cheney.net/2017/08/20/context-isnt-for-cancellation which is why I am not marking it as the answer.

Comment: @johne: you seem to be misinterpreting that blog post. While Dave may wish that context and cancellation be separated in some way in the future, there's no denying that Context is currently how cancellations are handled in Go. In fact, the std library almost exclusively uses Contexts for cancelation. Just looks at the use in the `net` package for example, along with `os/exec`, `net/http` and so on. Even more specific, the `Cancel` channel in an `http.Request` states: `Deprecated: Set the Request's context with NewRequestWithContext instead.`

Comment: I don't think you can reuse the cancellation context in multiple routines.  If you check the source code of `context.WithCancel` you'll see that there is a single channel lazily created when you call `Done()`. If you get multiple routines receiving from this single channel, only one of them will receive the cancellation signal.

Comment: @Roman I don't think johne was referring to multiple calls over several routines, but multiple calls in the same routine.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm: it's totally ok to use it with multiple routines. Even though it uses a single channel, the implementation is based on closing that channel to deliver the cancellation signal, not sending some value. And while sending a value reaches only one of the receiving routines, closing the channel reaches all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Use close on a channel to signal completion. This allows multiple goroutines to check for completion by receiving on the channel.

Use one channel per goroutine to signal completion of the goroutine.

```
done1 := make(chan struct{}) // closed when goroutine 1 returns
done2 := make(chan struct{}) // closed when goroutine 2 returns

go func() {
    defer close(done1)

    timer1 := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    defer timer1.Stop()

    timer2 := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
    defer timer2.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done2:
            // The other goroutine returned.
            fmt.Println("done func 1")
            return
        case <-timer1.C:
            fmt.Println("timer1 func 1")
        case <-timer2.C:
            fmt.Println("timer2 func 1")
            return
        }

    }
}()

go func() {
    defer close(done2)
    for {
        select {
        case <-done1:
            // The other goroutine returned.
            fmt.Println("done func 2")
            return
        default:
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("sleep done from func 2")
            return
        }

    }
}()

fmt.Println("waiting for goroutines to complete")

// Wait for both goroutines to return. The order that
// we wait here does not matter. 
<-done1
<-done2

fmt.Println("all done")
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pMgVjwaKzHT).

Answer (score 2):

First separate the waiting on go-routines and the `done` channel.

Use a `sync.WaitGroup` to coordinate the goroutines.

```golang
func main() {
    wait := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    N := 3

    wait.Add(N)
    for i := 1; i <= N; i++ {
        go goFunc(wait, i, true)
    }

    wait.Wait()
    fmt.Println(`Exiting main`)
}
```

Each goroutine will look like this:

```golang
// code for the actual goroutine
func goFunc(wait *sync.WaitGroup, i int, closer bool) {
    defer wait.Done()
    defer fmt.Println(`Exiting `, i)

    T := time.Tick(time.Duration(100*i) * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-T:
            fmt.Println(`Tick `, i)
            if closer {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/mDO4P56lzBU)

Our main func is successfully waiting for the goroutines to exit before it exits. Each goroutine is closing itself, and we want a way to cancel all our goroutines at the same time.

We'll do this with a `chan`, and make use of this feature of receiving from channels:

QUOTE: A receive operation on a closed channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's zero value after any previously sent values have been received. 
(https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)

We modify our goroutines to check for a CLOSE:

```golang
func goFunc(wait *sync.WaitGroup, i int, closer bool, CLOSE chan struct{}) {
    defer wait.Done()
    defer fmt.Println(`Exiting `, i)

    T := time.Tick(time.Duration(100*i) * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-CLOSE:
            return
        case <-T:
            fmt.Println(`Tick `, i)
            if closer {
                close(CLOSE)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then we change our `func main` so that it passes the CLOSE channel through, and we'll set the `closer` variable so that only the last of our goroutines will trigger the close:

```golang
func main() {
    wait := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    N := 3
    CLOSE := make(chan struct{})

    // Launch the goroutines
    wait.Add(N)
    for i := 1; i <= N; i++ {
        go goFunc(wait, i, i == N, CLOSE)
    }

    // Wait for the goroutines to finish
    wait.Wait()
    fmt.Println(`Exiting main`)
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/E91CtRAHDp2)

Now it looks like everything is working.

But it isn't. **Concurrency is hard.** There's a bug lurking in this code, just waiting to bite you in production. Let's surface it.

Change our example so that *every* goroutine will close:

```golang
func main() {
    wait := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    N := 3
    CLOSE := make(chan struct{})

    // Launch the goroutines
    wait.Add(N)
    for i := 1; i <= N; i++ {
        go goFunc(wait, i, true /*** EVERY GOROUTINE WILL CLOSE ***/, CLOSE)
    }

    // Wait for the goroutines to finish
    wait.Wait()
    fmt.Println(`Exiting main`)
}
```

Change goroutine so that it takes a while before closing. We want two goroutines to be about to close at the same time:

```golang
// code for the actual goroutine
func goFunc(wait *sync.WaitGroup, i int, closer bool, CLOSE chan struct{}) {
    defer wait.Done()
    defer fmt.Println(`Exiting `, i)

    T := time.Tick(time.Duration(100*i) * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-CLOSE:
            return
        case <-T:
            fmt.Println(`Tick `, i)
            if closer {
                /*** TAKE A WHILE BEFORE CLOSING ***/
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
                close(CLOSE)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/YHnbDpnJCks)

We crash with:

```
Tick  1
Tick  2
Tick  3
Exiting  1
Exiting  2
panic: close of closed channel

goroutine 7 [running]:
main.goFunc(0x40e020, 0x2, 0x68601, 0x430080)
    /tmp/sandbox558886627/prog.go:24 +0x2e0
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox558886627/prog.go:38 +0xc0

Program exited: status 2.
```

While a receive on a closed channel returns immediately, you cannot close a closed channel.

We need a little coordination. We can do this with a `sync.Mutex` and a `bool` to indicate whether we've closed the channel or not. Let's create a struct to do this:

```golang
type Close struct {
    C chan struct{}
    l sync.Mutex
    closed bool
}

func NewClose() *Close {
    return &Close {
        C: make(chan struct{}),
    }
}

func (c *Close) Close() {
    c.l.Lock()
    if (!c.closed) {
        c.closed=true
        close(c.C)
    }
    c.l.Unlock()
}
```

Rewrite our gofunc and our main to use our new Close struct, and we're good to go:
https://play.golang.org/p/eH3djHu8EXW

The problem with concurrency is that you always need to be wondering what would happen if another 'thread' was anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you want a *single* send on the DONE channel to be received by *multiple* listeners. You also need to consider whether a send on the `done` channel is received by your goroutines, or by your `main` func.

I suggest you rather separate the waiting on go-routines and the `done` channel.

```golang
import `sync`

// This code will wait for the two functions to complete before ending
func main {
   var wait sync.WaitGroup
   wait.Add(2)
   go func() {
     defer wait.Done()
   }()
   go g() {
     defer wait.Done()
   }()
   wait.Wait()
}
```

Now, how to manage the Done. Well, the solution is to use a `sync.Cond` and have each goroutine run its own goroutine to wait on the Cond. Here's an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    `fmt`
    `sync`
    `time`
)

// WaitForIt wraps a Cond and a Mutex for a simpler API:
// .WAIT() chan struct{} will return a channel that will be
//   signalled when the WaitForIt is done.
// .Done() will indicate that the WaitForIt is done.
type WaitForIt struct {
    L *sync.Mutex
    Cond *sync.Cond
}

func NewWaitForIt() *WaitForIt {
    l := &sync.Mutex{}
    c := sync.NewCond(l)
    return &WaitForIt{ l, c }
}

// WAIT returns a chan that will be signalled when
// the Cond is triggered.
func (w *WaitForIt) WAIT() chan struct{} {
    D := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        w.L.Lock()
        defer w.L.Unlock()
        w.Cond.Wait()
        D <- struct{}{}
        close(D)
    }()
    return D
}

// Done indicates that the Cond should be triggered.
func (w *WaitForIt) Done() {
    w.Cond.Broadcast()
}

// doneFunc launches the func f with a chan that will be signalled when the
// func should stop. It also handles WaitGroup synchronization
func doneFunc(wait *sync.WaitGroup, waitForIt *WaitForIt, f func(DONE chan struct{})) {
    defer wait.Done()
    f(waitForIt.WAIT())
}

func main() {
    // wait will coordinate all the goroutines at the level of main()
    // between themselves the waitForIt will do the coordination
    wait := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    // waitForIt indicates to the goroutines when they should shut
    waitForIt := NewWaitForIt()

    // goFunc generates each goroutine. Only the 3-second goroutine will 
    // shutdown all goroutines
    goFunc := func(seconds int) func(chan struct{}) {
        return func(DONE chan struct{}) {
            // this is the actual code of each goroutine
            // it makes a ticker for a number of seconds,
            // and prints the seconds after the ticker elapses,
            // or exits if DONE is triggered
            timer := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
            defer timer.Stop()
            for {
                select {
                case <- DONE:
                    return
                case <- timer.C:
                    if (3==seconds) {
                        waitForIt.Done()
                        // Don't shutdown here - we'll shutdown
                        // when our DONE is signalled
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // launch 3 goroutines, each waiting on a shutdown signal
    for i:=1; i<=3; i++ {
        wait.Add(1)
        go doneFunc(wait, waitForIt, goFunc(i))
    }
    // wait for all the goroutines to complete, and we're done
    wait.Wait()
}
```

Here's your example implemented using WaitForIt: https://play.golang.org/p/llphW73G1xE
Note that I had to remove the `Lock()` call in `WaitForIt.Done`. Although the documentation says you're allowed to hold the lock, it was blocking your 2nd goroutine from completing.

Comment: You have articulated my problem precisely and much better than I did. Between you and the comment by Cerise, I have a good idea on how to solve this. Am I missing something here? Ignore the waiting on both goroutines being done. Or is using sync.Cond a necessity in such cases? https://play.golang.org/p/RVUgIIggTJ3

Comment: I tested that a little bit more and I run into send on closed channels. I need to read up on sync.Cond (and its making my head spin trying to understand whats going on), but this looks like the correct answer.

Comment: You shouldn't be runnning into closed channels with the WaitForIt class. `sync.Cond` is indeed a little tricky, but it's exactly what you want for these situations: it's a conditional, with the ability for a number of goroutines to wait on a condition. The WAIT channel stuff is just to convert the conditional into a `chan` so that you can access it within a `select`. I'll see if I can create a play example using `WaitForIt` with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use channel closing pattern to wait within multiple go routines.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
)


type RunGroup struct {
  sync.WaitGroup
}

// Run handles wait group state
func (runGroup *RunGroup) Run(f func()) {
  runGroup.Add(1)
  go func() {
    f()
    runGroup.Done()
  }()
}

func doStuff(done <-chan any, id int) {
  println("Doing something", id)
  <-done
  println("DONE", id)
}

func main() {
  // Done channel
  done := make(chan any)
  // Setup Shutdown listeners
  sigChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGTERM)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGINT)
  go func() {
    rawSig := <-sigChan
    sig := rawSig.String()
    println("Caught signal, shutting down.", sig)
    close(done)
  }()

  runGroup := RunGroup{}
  // Do some stuff
  runGroup.Run(func () {
    doStuff(done, 1)
  })
  runGroup.Run(func () {
    doStuff(done, 2)
  })
  runGroup.Run(func () {
    doStuff(done, 3)
  })

  // Wait mainthread until interrupt
  runGroup.Wait()
}
```

Output

```bash
go run ./main.go
Doing something 3
Doing something 2
Doing something 1
^CCaught signal, shutting down. interrupt
DONE 3
DONE 1
DONE 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func func1(done chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    timer1 := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    timer2 := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case <-timer1.C:
            fmt.Println("timer1 func 1")
        case <-timer2.C:
            // Ask GC to sweep the tickers timer1, timer2
            // as goroutine should return
            timer1.Stop()
            timer2.Stop()

            fmt.Println("timer2 func 1")

            done <- struct{}{} // Signal the other goroutine to terminate

            fmt.Println("sent done from func 1")
            return
        case <-done:
            // Ask GC to sweep the tickers timer1, timer2
            // as goroutine should return
            timer1.Stop()
            timer2.Stop()

            fmt.Println("done func 1")
            return

        }

    }
}

func func2(done chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    timer3 := time.NewTicker(3 * time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case <-timer3.C:
            // Ask GC to sweep the tickers timer3
            // as goroutine should return
            timer3.Stop()

            fmt.Println("timer3 func 2")

            done <- struct{}{} // Signal the other goroutine to terminate

            fmt.Println("sent done from func 2")
            return
        case <-done:
            // Ask GC to sweep the tickers timer3
            // as goroutine should return
            timer3.Stop()
            fmt.Println("done func 2")
            return
        }

    }
}

func main() {
    // Chan used for signalling between goroutines
    done := make(chan struct{})

    // WaitGroup
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    wg.Add(2)

    // Spawn the goroutine for func1
    go func1(done, &wg)
    // Spawn the goroutine for func2
    go func2(done, &wg)

    fmt.Println("starting sleep")

    // Wait for the goroutines
    wg.Wait()

    // Wait for 15 seconds
    // If not required, please remove
    // the lines below
    time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("waited 15 seconds")

}
```